# Pyinstaller. Текстовые файлы с данными

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Я скомпилировал проект python в .exe с помощью pyinstaller. При запуске приложения появляется интерфейс, который я создал на PySide2. Однако, при нажатии на кнопки, программа не выполняется (в моем случае должен был построен график из рассчитанных программой значений исходя из данных в текстовом документе, который лежит в одной папке и исполняемым файлом /py). Если кратко, то exe-файл вообще не знает об существовании текстовых документов и что оттуда надо брать данные. До перевода директории в .exe все нормально работает. Вопрос: где уже в готовой директории с исполняемым exe-файлом находятся эти текстовые данные? Если нет, то как сделать так, чтобы при переводе директории проекта из .py в .exe эти файлы были использованы программой?

P.S. для перевода проекта в exe использую следующую команду:

```
pyinstaller --onedir -w main.py
```

Comment: Скажи пайинсталеру что ты хочешь добавить файлы, он поймёт.

Comment: @Александр а можно разъяснить как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы компилируете проект Python в .exe с помощью PyInstaller, текстовые файлы не включаются автоматически. Чтобы включить их, вы можете использовать опцию --add-data при запуске PyInstaller. Например, чтобы включить текстовый файл data.txt, который находится в той же папке, что и main.py, вы можете использовать

```
pyinstaller --add-data "data.txt;." --onedir -w main.py
```